# Sorting 271,568 Files in Bash Based on File Names

Tags: linux, bash, file, sorting, filesystems

I have a collection of 271,568 files I need to sort, all in the same directory. Luckily, they are all conveniently named based on what folder they should be in.

For example, a small portion of the files might look like:

```
.
├── file.sort.shamwow
├── file.sort.shamwow.abc
├── file.sort.shamwow.example.alsoafile
├── file.sort.shamwow.example.file
├── foo.bar
├── foo.bar.a
├── foo.bar.b
├── foo.lel
├── foo.wow.a.50
└── foo.wow.b
```

When they are finished being sorted, they should look like:

```
.
├── file
│   └── sort
│       └── shamwow
│           ├── example
│           │   ├── file.sort.shamwow.example.alsoafile
│           │   └── file.sort.shamwow.example.file
│           ├── file.sort.shamwow
│           └── file.sort.shamwow.abc
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   ├── foo.bar
    │   ├── foo.bar.a
    │   └── foo.bar.b
    ├── foo.lel
    └── wow
        ├── foo.wow.a.50
        └── foo.wow.b
```

So that file `foo.wow.a.50` would be placed inside of directory `wow` that is inside of directory `foo`, and so on for all the files.

The program I want would sort the files based on where the dots are into directories. However, if there is only one file in that folder (ex. `foo/wow/a.50`) then it won't create a new folder just for that file.

Right now, my half-functional script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#organization for gigantic folder

> foo.txt

for f in *; do
    d=${f:3}
    d=${d%%.*}
    d=${d%%.*}
    echo $d

    if grep -Fxq "$d" foo.txt
    then
        mkdir -p $d
        mv $f $d
    else
        echo $d >> foo.txt
    fi
done

rm foo.txt
```

But it doesn't really work that well.

**Can someone either fix my code, or make their own to sort this mess?** Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest taking the `ls` reference out of your question -- it would tend to get you a bunch of links to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, whereas your question doesn't actually require any use of `ls` at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the suggestion. I changed it to "Sorting 271,568 Files in Bash Based on File Names."

Comment: BTW, you can't have three *files* named `foo/bar`, `foo/bar/a` and `foo/bar/b`, the directory name for the latter two will conflict with the file name for the former.

Comment: I'm with Duffy; at a minimum you will need to know how you want to handle the foo.bar case: A file in foo/ called foo.bar? a file in foo/bar/ also called bar? Skip it?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question wrong. I edited it, but just know that directory foo contains directory bar which contains files foo.bar, foo.bar.a, and foo.bar.b.

Comment: So shouldn't your desired output have `foo/wow/a.50` `foo/wow/b` instead of `foo/wow.a.50` `foo/wow.b`?

Comment: My current representation isn't working, so I made another one using `tree`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that your requested output is impossible to represent on a filesystem (requires the same names to refer to both a file and a directory):

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- must be bash shebang, must be shell 4.0 or newer

# first pass: count directory references
declare -A refcounts=( )
for f in *; do
  f_part=$f
  while [[ $f_part = *.* ]]; do
    refcounts[$f_part]=$(( ${refcounts[$f_part]} + 1 ))
    f_part=${f_part%.*}
  done
  refcounts[$f_part]=$(( ${refcounts[$f_part]} + 1 ))
done

# second pass: use that information
# ...this is some ugly code, but I don't have the time right now to make it simpler.
for f in *; do
  f_part=${f%%.*}
  f_rest=${f#*.}
  while : "f=$f; f_part=$f_part; f_rest=$f_rest"; do
    new_piece=${f_rest%%.*}
    [[ $new_piece ]] || break
    f_part_next=${f_part}.$new_piece
    f_rest_next=${f_rest#"$new_piece"}; f_rest_next=${f_rest_next#.}
    if [[ $f_rest = *.* ]] && (( ${refcounts[${f_part_next}]:-0} > 1 )); then
      f_part=$f_part_next
      f_rest=$f_rest_next
    else
      break
    fi
  done
  dest="${f_part//"."/"/"}/${f_rest}"
  mkdir -p -- "${dest%/*}"
  mv -- "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Got a lot of mkdir and mv errors. It half-worked. I think one problem that I think I miscommunicated is that the program didn't need to rename the files. That would probably make it work.

Comment: The edits to your question make this answer quite invalid. As the opening paragraph says, it attempts to do the impossible thing you initially asked for -- so of *course* it's expected to fail. :)

Comment: ...that said, the general gist of it -- the two-pass design, building up a table of reference counts in the first pass and performing filesystem operations in the second -- holds true. The only changes you need to make this work for your new and different question will be in the second pass -- and the new code should be considerably simpler than what it replaces.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I will try to do that.

Comment: BTW, as a performance optimization, I'd consider moving the `mkdir`s out of the second loop -- if you're just doing one for every directory with a refcount of 2 or greater, you could just iterate over key/value pairs and do it from there without ever running `mkdir` more than once for the same directory. Something like: `for k in "${!refcounts[@]}"; do v=${refcounts[$k]}; if (( v > 1 )); then printf '%s\0' "$k"; fi; done | xargs -0 mkdir -p --`